# All day event icalendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar

I am using the below to setup an event to export to ical with the icalendar gem.

```
@calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new

event = Icalendar::Event.new
event.dtstart = ev.start_at.strftime("%Y%m%d")
event.dtend = ev.end_at.strftime("%Y%m%d")
event.summary = ev.summary

@calendar.add
```

In order to make an event all day it needs to look like this:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20101117
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20101119
```

Right now I am using

```
event.dtstart = "$VALUE=DATE:"+ev.start_at.strftime("%Y%m%d")"
```

This will output

```
DTSTART:$VALUE=DATE:20101117
```

and then I replace all ":$" with ";" with

```
@allday = @calendar.to_ical.gsub(":$", ";")
```

Is there a more direct way to save dates as all day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with this and figured out one way. You can assign properties to the event dates, in the form of key-value pairs. so you could assign the VALUE property like so:

```
event = Icalendar::Event.new
event.dtstart = Date.new(2010,12,1)
event.dtstart.ical_params = { "VALUE" => "DATE" }
puts event.to_ical

# output
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20101201T230134
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20101201
SEQUENCE:0
UID:2010-12-01T23:01:34-08:00_923426206@ubuntu
END:VEVENT
```

Now the fun part. Given a calendar you can create an event and pass in a block which initializes the date with its properties:

```
calendar.event do
  dtstart Date.new(2010,11,17), ical_params = {"VALUE"=>"DATE"}
  dtend Date.new(2010,11,19), ical_params = {"VALUE"=>"DATE"}
end
```

Comment: This seems like a much better approach. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

So this thread seems quite old (and did not solve the problem with the most recent version of the icalendar gem - 2.3.0).  I've recently had to create "all day" calendar events in ics format.  I've found this to be a much better solution (and seems to work the way you'd expect calendars to handle it) - see the snippet below

```
date = Date.new(2010,11,17)
event = Icalendar::Event.new
event.dtstart = Icalendar::Values::Date.new date
event.dtstart.ical_param "VALUE", "DATE"
event.dtend = Icalendar::Values::Date.new (date + 1.day)
event.dtend.ical_param "VALUE", "DATE"
puts event.to_ical
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150521T162712Z
UID:4c239930-15ba-44b4-a045-c6fae3d858d2
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20101117
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20101118
END:VEVENT
```

Note that the Date does not have a time associated with it.  The code in the prior reply currently produces the time.  I had to dig into the source code for icalendar to figure out this solution.

I hope this helps someone else.

Cheers!